# pentaho column level validation

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am new in Pentaho project. Need to know about some validation rules whether these can be handled by PDI or not.
My input data is CSV format and target is ORACLE table. Suppose total number of column is 50.

**Validation Rules :**

- if any less number of columns coming from input file (like 48) we
  should inform via email
- if any more number of columns coming from input file (like 54) we
  should inform via email
- if there are any duplicate columns coming in input file we should
  inform via email
- if there a missing order in input file with respect to target table
  layout we should inform via email
- if there any columns started with a number we should inform via email
- if there any columns more than 30 characters in length we should
  inform via email

Any help is appreciated.

If anything required from me kindly reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are steps that will allow you to identify all of these things.

More generally, if you want to do something in Kettle and don't see a step available that makes it easy to do, you can always write custom steps or steps with custom Java or JavaScript code in them to do it.

Comment: thanx @gordon .... can u just guide me a little bit about the custom steps.... I have made a text file that contains all the target column list and use this as a file comparison with on-the-fly source file metadata... this helps me for validate all the column list...but i faced a problem..if source file changes all the metadata is not refreshing automatically ... i have to refresh them manually and run....is there any option on that????

Answer (score 1):

After lots of R&D it can be done by adding "Metadata Structure" under Utility in Transformation and load all column list into a text file.

Then create a Job and compare this text file with lookup text file (containing all target column list) by "File Compare" under File Management. Make a check option if true then invoke the final Transformation or if False send email notification.